# Run portainer in a docker container: unix:///var/run/docker.sock access denied

Tags: docker, ubuntu, portainer

I am trying to run portainer in a docker container, but it fails with the following error:

> failed to determine container platform: failed to retrieve docker
> info: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker
> daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

This is the command line to create the container:

```
docker run -d \
  --userns host \
  --user 1002:1002 \
  -v /docker/_volumes/portainer:/data \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:z \
  portainer/portainer-ce
```

The user and group 1002 are the host's `portainer-user` user:

```
$ id -u portainer-user
1002
$ id -g portainer-user
1002
```

This user belongs to the `docker` group on the host:

```
$ groups portainer-user
portainer-user : portainer-user docker
```

The sock file is configured to allow access to the docker group:

```
$ ls -al /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 root docker /var/run/docker.sock
```

Docker is using user remap:

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "userns-remap": "default"
}
```

And the docker service is configured like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

I tried multiple things, including removing the `:z` in `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:z` without success.